# using initial on django MultipleChoiceField on many-to-many relation

Tags: python, django

In my model, I have:

```
    flowcell = models.ForeignKey("FlowCell", on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    lanes = models.ManyToManyField("main.FlowCellLane", related_name='demuxers', blank=True)
```

in my form, I want these to be selectable, based on available FlowCellLanes. So I pop flowcell to a variable and use it to see which 'Lanes' are there:

```
class DemuxerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Demuxer
        exclude = ["owner", "pid", "flowcell"]

    lanes = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.flowcell = kwargs.pop('flowcell')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['lanes'].choices = sorted([(lane.pk, str(lane.lane_number))
                                               for lane in self.flowcell.lanes.all()])
```

Now I would like to have all available checkboxes checked. But I don't know how I could do that. At the spot where initial= could be, 'self' is off course not available... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
choices = self.flowcell.lanes.values_list("pk", lane_number").order_by("lane_number")
self.fields['lanes'].choices = choices
self.fields["lanes"].initial = [pk for pk, _ in choices]
```